# Wait for a particular duration before automatic option selection

Tags: shell, tcsh

```
echo "Select option: Enter 1 or 2. (1. cakes 2. coffee)"  
set selection=$<  
...
```

I want to wait for 40 seconds for user input. If there is no user input within this delay time, I want to automatically set selection as 1. How can I achieve this in tcsh?

Also welcome solutions in bash or csh.

Comment: at  a bash prompt, enter `help read` and look at the `-t` option